Optimal gain for RF pulse detection in RTLSDR
I'm trying to optimize the SNR of low-power RF pulses (from wildlife telemetry tags @166Mhz, unmodulated, a few DBs above noise floor) as they go into an RTLSDR. The detection performs windowed FFTs and then convolves each frequency with a 2.5ms square pulse profile, i.e. looking for 2.5ms long RF pulses at each frequency. The key here is to maximise SNR in order to be able to detect as faint RF pulses as possible.
The question I have is how to perform AGC, specifically, what the target of the AGC should be. The ADC in the RTLSDR only has 8 bit resolution, i.e. about 50dB tops. The amplitude of the expected RF pulses is unknown and there may be nothing for days and then suddenly a series of pulses arrive, so this is not a situation where the AGC can continuously track the signal. Rather, the AGC needs to set the noise at some level and "hope" this provides the best resolution for the signals.
The two options I have been considering:

Define a max expected SNR, say 20dB, so place the noise around -20dB and hope that any stronger signals can still be received OK (there are issues when pulses saturate the RX which typ manifest themselves in incorrect frequency estimation)
Place the noise close to the floor of the ADC, e.g. somewhere around -40dB

I have a hard time understanding whether a low power signal (say 6dB above noise when coming into ADC) is best resolved when near the top of the ADC range or the bottom.
